# Hexacopter Vn diagram/ flight envelope/ operational envelope

Tags: aerodynamics, flight-controls, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, flight-dynamics

I am currently intern at a company. They are making agriculture hexacopter, now there is a confusion that does the hexacopter or multicopter have a V n diagram if yes how to make one what's the correct way, and what is the operational and flight envelope for multicopter? So confusion any help

Comment: There's no expert and/or senior engineer in that company you can ask about these subjects? Or is it a start-up that has never done helicopters before?

Answer (score 1):

Vn diagrams for multicopters are a *bit* pointless. A normal flight envelope is used to convey to the pilot where the limits are and why they are at that specific point. This is often important, as you might have several limits which come to play, such as structural limits, stall limits, power limits and so on. Keeping track of all these limitations in order not to damage the aircraft for example, is a critical task for a pilot hence the flight envelope diagram.

For a multicopter however, all of this is not important because they have typically only one very uncritical limit: The power. Having said that, I *speculate* that the Vn diagram of a multicopter looks similar to the following picture:

[image]

Please be aware, that I did not calculate this envelope. Therefore I am not exactly sure if the power limit is a straight line, but it should at least resemble this graph.

I hope this answers your question at least in parts.

Comment: Okay got the point, so i guess there is no calculation or diagram that depicts these limits, i saw velocity height diagram for helicopter thought that is similar for multicopter, then how the operational envelope for a multicopter is decided, lets say i have to design a hexacopter drone, how do i calculate its operational/flight envelope. any way to do this ?